# mapper_parsing_exception for a custom analyzer while creating index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I create an index named `test` via a `PUT` request using:

```
PUT http://localhost:9250/test
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "&_to_and": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": ["& => and"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "my_stopwords": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["the", "a"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "type":         "custom",
                    "char_filter":  ["html_strip", "&_to_and"],
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "filter":       ["lowercase", "my_stopwords"]
                },
                "folding": {
                    "token_filters": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "type": "custom"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "tweet": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "author": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "my_analyzer",
                    "store": true
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "folding",
                    "store": true
                },
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                    "store": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "wrong value for index [my_analyzer] for field [author]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [tweet]: wrong value for index [my_analyzer] for field [author]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "wrong value for index [my_analyzer] for field [author]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The json that I am sending seems to be valid. What is the reason of this error?

I am using ES 2.2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message describes custom-analyzer's such as  `my_analyzer` are not  valid values for `index`option in mapping. The only values it can take as per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html) are

> **no**
>
> Do not add this field value to the index. With this setting, the field
>   will not be queryable.
>
> **not_analyzed**
>
> Add the field value to the index unchanged, as a single term. This is
>   the default for all fields that support this option except for string
>   fields. not_analyzed fields are usually used with term-level queries
>   for structured search.
>
> **analyzed**
>
> This option applies only to string fields, for which it is the
>   default. The string field value is first analyzed to convert the
>   string into terms (e.g. a list of individual words), which are then
>   indexed. At search time, the query string is passed through (usually)
>   the same analyzer to generate terms in the same format as those in the
>   index. It is this process that enables full text search.

If you wanted to set a custom-analyzer for a field use the [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html) option

Example:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "&_to_and": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": ["& => and"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "my_stopwords": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["the", "a"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "type":         "custom",
                    "char_filter":  ["html_strip", "&_to_and"],
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "filter":       ["lowercase", "my_stopwords"]
                },
                "folding": {
                    "token_filters": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "type": "custom"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "tweet": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "author": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                    "store": true
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "folding",
                    "store": true
                },
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                    "store": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! ok. That was such a bad mistake.
Thanks!